# Apply jQuery selector to a container AND its descendants

Tags: jquery

With jQuery I can easily find/select all elements inside a container that match a given selector:

```
$('.some_class', container);
```

But what if I want to include the container itself, if it matches the selector?

I think the following would do the trick.

```
$('.some_class', container).add($(container).filter('.some_class'));
```

But is there an easier way? Ideally something where I don't have to repeat the selector.

### Expected behavior

```
<div class="container common">
  <div class="child common"></div>
</div>
```

The following function does what I want, I am just wondering if there is a simpler solution out of the box.

```
function findInContainerAndDescendants(selector, $container) {
  return $(selector, context).add($(context).filter(selector));
}

var $container = $('.container');
findInContainerAndDescendants('.common', $container)  -> both container and child.
findInContainerAndDescendants('.child', $container)  -> just the child.
```

Comment: Tried `container.find('.some_class').addBack()`?

Comment: Interesting. I think we still need to apply the filter though. So `container.find('.some_class').addBack('.some_class')`.

Comment: No, `addBack` knows the first element(s). BTW, if you have `jQuery < v3`, use `addSelf()` instead. See: https://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Comment: The goal was to only re-add the first elements if they match the selector. This is why I have the .filter() in the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addBack() (jQuery >= 3.0)` or `addSelf() (jQuery < 3.0)`:

```js
function findInContainerAndDescendants(selector, context) {
  return context.find(selector).addBack(selector);
}
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Add see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8cy09vq/

Comment: This will add the container unconditionally. What I want is to only add the container if it matches.

Comment: What do you mean by `unconditionally`? It is adding the first matching elements of the chain by the selector.

Comment: But it also adds the container if it does not match the selector '.some_class'.

Comment: Isn't `some_class` the class for the children of the container? So your container also has class `some_class`?

Comment: The container may or may not have this class. It is coming as a function parameter, so we know very little about it at the time the function runs. Depending whether or not it has the class, it should be added to the selection or not.

Comment: Ok. Now it is a correct answer. I was hoping for something out of the box, but perhaps this does not exist.

Comment: My bad. `addBack` accepts `selector` as an argument. So we can simplify it as my updated answer. You were actually correct in your first comment under your question..